# Jenkins gradle build error on integrating crashlytics fabric with Android studio

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

I am using Jenkins and trying to build Android Studio project  which uses the crashlytics new Fabric.

I am also using gradle 2.2.1

I get error from the following in the Jenkins log-

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.fabric']
  >   Could not create plugin of type 'CrashlyticsPlugin'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer helped me fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704482/jenkins-build-fails-on-crashalytics-tasks/23944306#23944306

Comment: I tried that. But its not helping me. I get the same error again.

Comment: @Sayooj Please refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704482/jenkins-build-fails-on-crashlytics-tasks/32712878#32712878

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704482/jenkins-build-fails-on-crashlytics-tasks/32712878#32712878