# Android Jenkins build fails with crashlytics

Tags: android, jenkins, crashlytics

Everytime I try to build using Jenkins I get the following error

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.fabric']
>   Could not create plugin of type 'CrashlyticsPlugin'.

Removing Crashlytics from Gradle fixes this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704482/jenkins-build-fails-on-crashlytics-tasks/32712878#32712878

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think I fixed it by using a combination of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944306/3945542 with @TarahWheelerVanVlack answer I had to create two new folders

/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Caches

And then make sure they had the proper permissions

Answer (score 6):

These are the final commands that you need to follow:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library
```

Here is the relavant debug log for this case:

```
13:33:45.133 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.<clinit>(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:13)
13:33:45.135 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:48)
13:33:45.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:69)
13:33:45.136 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 55 more
13:33:45.141 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crashlytics data directory at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics could not be created.
13:33:45.142 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.<clinit>(DeveloperTools.java:116)
13:33:45.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 60 more
13:33:45.143 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:33:45.144 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
13:33:45.145 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
13:33:45.146 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
13:33:45.147 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 8.362 secs
```

Comment: Thank you: Adding following line worked for me in Mac: mkdir -p /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before and it was a permissions error. Try checking permissions and the user who owns the plugins directory. If it's not the Jenkins user (if you've created one), then that's the issue.

Comment: I checked the permissions and they should be fine. (I assume the plugins directory is in the tree mentioned below by Jenkins) Still getting this message FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Hampton/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.fabric']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'CrashlyticsPlugin'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 1):

Create directory
`/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/Caches`

If you run `./gradlew clean --stacktrace` from the job workspace `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/<job-name>/workspace` you get the following stacktrace

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crashlytics data directory at >/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics could not be created.
>     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.(DeveloperTools.java:116)
>       ... 53 more

Comment: Adding the Caches directory worked for me, though I didn't see the runtime error in the console messages when building.