# Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.fabric']

Tags: android, jenkins

I use fabric.io plugin for my Android project.

> classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.14.4'

Last time I tried to set up the project on Jenkins but when executing

> gradle clean build

I get:

```
Failed to apply plugin ['io.fabric']
> Could not create plugin of type 'CrashlyticsPlugin'.
```

When the plugin is at the beginning of build.gradle file:

> apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

I also get:

```
IllegalArgumentException: android.compileSdkVersion is missing!
```

And the error above.
What is wrong with **fabric** plugin?

Comment: May I see the full `build.gradle` file content? It seems like that you forget to put something like: android { compileSdkVersion 21 ... }

Comment: I have both:
    compileSdkVersion, 
    buildToolsVersion

Comment: Solution from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714272/android-jenkins-build-fails-with-crashlytics
doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

i am phase same problem and at last finding solution with this link [Integration Twitter In Android Studio Application...](https://fabric.io/downloads/android-studio)

1> Download **FabricAndroidStudioPlugin**

2> Plugin into studio step-by-step

3> Sign in to application inside studio and install a kit which you want   to integrate

There are three available Kit :

```
    1> Crashlytics: light Weight & powerful crash-reporting
    2> Twitter: integrate login with twitter and E.T.C
    3> MoPub: monetize your application with Add platform
```

Android Studio Version: 1.1.0

Comment: It works in Android Studio but doesn't work when compiled from console in jenkins !

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Cause: android.compileSdkVersion is missing!