# Jenkins build failed with crashlytics

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, server

Trying to build android in Jenkins with crashlytics but every-time the error message is coming in log as

"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.fabric']
  >   Could not create plugin of type 'CrashlyticsPlugin'.
  >   Could not initialize class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin"

Please help, tried this way also "[Android Jenkins build fails with crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714272/android-jenkins-build-fails-with-crashlytics/27714295)" 
It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Crashlytics jar manuel into Jenkins. From [here](https://ssl-download-crashlytics-com.s3.amazonaws.com/android/ant/crashlytics.zip).
I guess the plug-in is facing some problems when downloading this file from Amazon.

You can check [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/fabric-beta-publisher-plugin/issues/9).

Comment: can you please tell me exactly, were to install this jar file.

Comment: Jenkins -> plugins -> fabric-beta-publisher -> WEB-INF

Comment: i have installed it in the same place and still i m getting the same error.  please help

Comment: Do you using proxy?